Jenkins Goals and options setup using Maven
I have for tests QA-1, QA-2, QA-3, and QA-4. In Jenkins and Cofigure, I added the four Bitbucket (git) branches' build paths. I added four tags (@QA-#) per each test, and for all tests I included another tag, QA-ALL. Is the following statement correct for me to run these four tests under one Jenkins build? Or must I have only one tag per branch per build?
test -pl :ifta -Denv=int2 -DaccountId=255264 -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=SetOfTestsRunner.java -Dcucumber.options="--tags 'not @ignore' --tags '@QA-ALL' --tags '@QA-1' --tags '@QA-2' --tags '@QA-3' --tags '@QA-4' " -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.haltafterfailure=true
Are the tags considered And or Or?
Any advice would be great.
